# engine.io / wss / SSL / HTTP : how to configure?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, websocket, socketstream

I'm using SocketStream (v 3.5) and have configured it to use the HTTPS server.  The page is served but the WebSocket connection fails somewhere in the Engine.io area.

I'm looking for clues as to how to proceed into the node_modules to configure the socket connection for SSL / WSS.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is essentially doubled with another.

The answer is to choose port 443 for the HTTPS server.

Not sure why yet.  Something in the WebSocket implementation in SocketStream and / or Engine.io.